# Complex Redirect all content to new folder without query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect everything in the folder **`\gallery1\`** to folder **`\gallery2\`**, which works fine except anything what comes after the **`xyz.php`** or **`zzz.php`** i.e.

- **`?photo=12345`** or
- **`?photo=12345&title=00000`** or
- **`?photo=12345&title=00000&cat=44444`**

what is happening is, that when the redirect from **`\gallery1\xyz.php?photo=12345&title=00000&cat=44444`** kicks in, it redirects to

**`\gallery2\?photo=12345&title=00000&cat=44444`**

obviously that's not what I want everything to be redirected to **`\gallery2\`** without anything comes after.

How can this be resolved using .htaccess i.e. redirect rules? Your help is greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^gallery1/(.*)$ /gallery2/$1? [L,NC,R=302]
```

- `?` after `$1` is for stripping of any existing query string
- Make sure there is no .htaccess inside `/gallery1/`